# New walker for walker_nav_menu to change inside container data

Tags: php, menus, walker

I'm not really good with coding, but I have googled a lot and edit some script and it worked, but I can't achieve what I need.

This is the code:

```
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
      function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array(), $id = 0)
      {
           global $wp_query;
           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

           $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

           $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

           $prepend = '<strong>';
           $append = '</strong>';
           $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

           if($depth != 0)
           {
                     $description = $append = $prepend = "";
           }

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
            $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args, $id );
            }
}
```

And In my .php file:

```
    <?php 
    wp_nav_menu( array(
     'container_class' => 'top-nav',
     'menu_class' => 'nav',
     'echo' => true,
     'before' => '',
     'after' => '',
     'link_before' => '',
     'link_after' => '',
     'depth' => 0,
     'theme_location' => 'topnav',
     'walker' => new description_walker())
     );
    ?>
```

The problem is I don't know how to add data for the container(the `div`) and the `ul` tag.

For example, this is what I'm getting:

```
<div class="top-nav">
<ul class="nav" ...>
<li ...></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And I want something like this:

```
<div class="top-nav" mine="something">
<ul class="nav" ... mine2="something2">
<li ...></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you wouldn't need a walker for that, if it's simply adding a `data` attribute or something like that you could just use the `items_wrap` parameter. [View `wp_nav_menu()` in Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/):

```
$items_wrap = '<div class="top-nav" mine="something">';
$items_wrap .= '<ul id="%1$s" mine="something2" class="nav %2$s">%3$s</ul>';
$items_wrap .= '</div>';

wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container'         => false,
    'echo'              => true,
    'before'            => '',
    'after'             => '',
    'link_before'       => '',
    'link_after'        => '',
    'depth'             => 0,
    'theme_location'    => 'topnav',
    'items_wrap'        => $items_wrap,     // The Default is: '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
    'walker'            => new description_walker()
) );
```

This is a more straight-froward way to do it than messing with a walker or something of the sort.

Comment: Oh... My... GOSH! You're amazing!!! I was looking for this walker class like three hours :) Thank you so much!!!